# How to append object in Mappable class(Model). iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, alamofire, objectmapper

In my app, I'm using `Alamofire-ObjectMapper`.

I have a `[OrderDetailSecond]`. now i want to use for loop for this array and when `isRxMedicine == 1` i want to add that object in any array so i can display that in my `UITableView`.

here is my code

this is my model

```
    class OrderDetailSecond: Mappable {

    var id : Int?
    var isRxMedicine : Int?
    var medicineTypeId : String?
    var name : String?
    var orderId : String?
    var price : String?
    var quentity : Int?
    var strength : String?

    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }

     func mapping(map: Map) {

        id <- map["id"]
        isRxMedicine <- map["is_rx_medicine"]
        medicineTypeId <- map["medicine_type_id"]
        name <- map["name"]
        orderId <- map["order_id"]
        price <- map["price"]
        quentity <- map["qty"]
        strength <- map["strengh"]
    }
}
```

now here i am trying to add objects in new element

```
if let Rx_OrderDetail = self.orderdetailInstance, Rx_detail = Rx_OrderDetail.result{
        let detailArray = Rx_detail[0].orederDetail

        if  let orderdata = detailArray
        {
            for RxDataFilter in orderdata
            {
                if (RxDataFilter.isRxMedicine == 1)
                {
                    array?.append(RxDataFilter)


                }

            }

            elementConunt = orderdata.count
        }
        return elementConunt

    }
```

but its not working

Note: orderdata is in form [OrderDetailSecond]

Comment: Are you sure that `array` is initialized at some point in your viewcontroller's lifecycle

Comment: yes its initialize. and even its append value in array but  then array is showing in [OrderDetailSecond] form. i want it in nsmuttablearray form. @ZellB.